# React Redux onBlur event not firing in Safari and Firefox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox, redux, react-redux

This seems to work perfectly in Chrome and Edge. I have a tooltip that needs to pop up onClick of the button, and then disappear onBlur. For some reason the onBlur event does not fire at all on Safari or Firefox.

I've tried logging to the console in handleBlur and it does not get that far, it is as if onBlur does not exist in this context.

```
class Tooltip extends Component {
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.closeActiveTooltip();
  }

  handleKeyPress = (event) => {
    if (event.keyCode === 27) { // Esc key
      this.closeActiveTooltip();
    }
  }

  handleBlur = () => {
    if (this.props.activeTooltip === this.props.name) {
      // setTimeout is for link click
      setTimeout(this.closeActiveTooltip, 100);
    }
  }

  closeActiveTooltip = () => {
    const { activeTooltip, closeTooltip } = this.props;

    if (activeTooltip) {
      closeTooltip(activeTooltip);
    }
  }

  render() {
    const {
      isOpen,
      text,
      link,
      position,
    } = this.props;
    const popupClassName = getClassNameFor(s, 'popup', `${isOpen && 'open'} ${position}`);
    const linkElement = (
      <div className={s.link}>
        <a
          href={link}
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          More info here
        </a>
      </div>
    );

    return (
      <button
        type="button"
        className={s.root}
        onClick={this.props.toggleTooltip}
        onBlur={this.handleBlur}
        onKeyDown={this.handleKeyPress}
      >
        <svg className={s.icon}>
          <use xlinkHref="#more-info" />
        </svg>
        <div className={popupClassName}>
          {text}
          {link && linkElement}
        </div>
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I know is that I could never get an element (most likely an `<input />`) focused on mount with React, probably because of `render()`s, so I use `setTimeout(() => input.focus(), 0)` to make it async. So, it seems there are issues with focus handling...

### A simple workaround would be:

```
<button
    onClick={this.handleAction}
    onMouseDown={this.handleFocus}
    onMouseUp={this.handleBlur} />
```

But when user release the mouse button *out of* the button, you'll never trigger the `onMouseUp`.

A better workaround consists in simulating a *click out*:

```
class Tooltip extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        document.body.addEventListener('click', this.handleClickOut, false);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        document.body.removeEventListener('click', this.handleClickOut, false);
    }

    handleClickOut = event => {
        if(event.target != this.refs.btn) { // Actually more complicated, event.target can be a child of button (icon, span, etc)
            this.handleBlur();
        }
    }

    handleBlur() {}

    render() {
        return (
            <button
                ref='btn'
                type="button"
            >
                {text}
            </button>
        );
    }
}
```

#### possibly with a component that wraps your button

```
<ClickOut onClickOut={this.handleBlur}>
    <button
        onClick={this.handleAction}
        onMouseDown={this.handleFocus} />
</ClickOut>
```

Any time you click on your document, if `target` is not `<button />` or one of its child nodes, trigger the *click out* pseudo event