# What is the alternative of OnBlur event in Mozilla Firefox browser?

Tags: reactjs, safari, cross-browser, mozilla

I'm using `onBlur` attribute for button in React js.
And the onBlur event works perfectly fine for Chrome but doesn't works for Safari and Firefox.
Please provide me with some alternative of onBlur event for Safari and Firefox.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44431931/react-redux-onblur-event-not-firing-in-safari-and-firefox/44432516

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar thanks. But this solution seems to be a workaround. Is there any other solution possible? :)

Comment: AFAIK, on blur event is mostly available for input fields, since you are trying it for button which may not be natively available for all browsers, your best bet is to have a workaround simulating the blur event.